# How can I concatenate these strings back together?

Tags: r, string

I would like to split a string into its elements and then paste them together again. However no matter what I tried, it doesn`t work.

Here are two things I've tried:

```
'hello' %>% strsplit('') %>% paste0()
```

output: `"c(\"h\", \"e\", \"l\", \"l\", \"o\")"`

```
'hello' %>% strsplit('') %>% unlist() %>% paste0()
```

output: `"h" "e" "l" "l" "o"`

I would simply like to get my 'hello' back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `paste` but you have to specify the `collapse` argument.

```
'hello' %>% strsplit('') %>% unlist() %>% paste(collapse = "")
```

Alternatively you can use `str_c` from the `stringr` library:

```
'hello' %>% strsplit('') %>% unlist() %>% stringr::str_c(collapse = "")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Can you tell me why it doesn't work with paste0()?

Comment: `paste` and `paste0`  without the collapse argument take multiple vectors as inputs (in your case 5 vectors each of length 1) and paste together their components and returns one vector of the same length as the input vectors. You can e.g. try `paste0(c("x", "y"), c(1, 100))`. If you specify collapse what paste will do **additionaly** is to collapse the output vector into a single character string: `paste0(c("x", "y"), c(1, 100), collapse = ";")`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to use `stringr::str_flatten` which explicitly does what you want:

```r
library(stringr)
'hello' %>% 
  strsplit('') %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  str_flatten()

# [1] "hello"
```

To avoid `unlist`, you can use `stringr::str_split` with `simplify = TRUE`:

```r
'hello' %>% 
  str_split('', simplify = T) %>% 
  str_flatten()
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try `unlist` + `as.list` + `do.call` along with `paste0` like below

```
"hello" %>%
  strsplit("") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  as.list() %>%
  do.call(paste0, .)
```